# Разработка ПО для iPhone на НЕ objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Есть ли какая-либо возможность писать программы на iPhone на чём то более привычном, при этому не теряя возможность продать их ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) - C#
2. [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) - Lua
3. [Cocos-X](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) - C++
4. [Rhodes](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) - Ruby
5. [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) - JavaScript
6. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - JavaScript
7. Уверен есть еще что-нибудь...

**ЗЫ.** из вопроса я не понял какой язык для вас "более привычный", но Objective-C очень и очень неплох: объектно-ориентированный, поддерживает интроспекцию, можно юзать в связке с С/С++, в общем классный он =)

Comment: Слышал не возможно продавать ПО если не использовался официальный SDK. Привычный - Java / C# )

Comment: Кажется то что вы слышали неправда

    http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps